# Arcpy script environment running question working space vs environment

Tags: python, arcgis, arcpy

So I'm doing the esri academy Arcpy exercises but theres something in the first exercise which I can't wrap my head around.
They provide a Spatial reference script and a Map layout script

Spatial reference script looks like

```
#import modules
import arcpy

#set workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\EsriTraining\PythEveryone\RunningScripts\Polk_County\OregonPolk.gdb"

#set up a describe object for each fc in geodatabase
fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
for fc in fcList:
    desc = arcpy.Describe(fc)
    print (desc.spatialReference.name)
print (fcList)
print ("Script completed")
```

and the Map layout script looks like

```
#import modules
import arcpy

#set environment
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")

#specify layout
lyt = aprx.listLayouts("PolkGrdWater")[0]

#list layout text elements
eleList = lyt.listElements("TEXT_ELEMENT")

#loop through list and find all text elements with "Polk County" title
for ele in eleList:
    if ele.text == "Polk County":
        ele.text = "Polk County, OR"

#refresh the active view
aprx.save()
del aprx

print ("Script completed")
```

I understand that the Map layout script is better suited to being run in the ArcGISpro Python window but what I don't understand is why I cant get the Map layout script to run in Pycharm in the same manner that I run the Spatial reference script, I thought if I changed the

```
#set environment
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
```

to

```
#set environment
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("Polk_County")
```

or

```
#set environment
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(r"C:\EsriTraining\PythEveryone\RunningScripts\Polk_County")
```

But i guess this has something to do with a lack of understanding the difference between setting the work environment and setting the workspace?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the right sort of input parameter in.

The object gets instantiated by passing in **a path to an ArcGIS Pro project** (an `.aprx` file).

If you're running this within ArcGIS Pro and have a project open already, then you can simply pass in `"CURRENT"` and the included Python interpreter understands that you mean "this Pro project's filepath." However, that won't work in Pycharm or a similar IDE, because *the script* doesn't have any reference for what project file you're talking about :)

So when you want to make an `ArcGISProject` object in a standalone script, provide the full path to the specific *project file*, not just the directory it's in... e.g.

```py
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(r"C:\EsriTraining\PythEveryone\Polk_County\Polk.aprx")
```

*Look at the Esri [Help page about an `ArcGISProject` object](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/arcgisproject-class.htm) for additional details and parameters.*

---

That issue isn't related to the `arcpy.env.workspace`, though. Depending on the particular arcpy function you're interested in, it may or may not require the [environment workspace](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/geoprocessing_and_python/using-environment-settings.htm) to be set. These are typically *data related* tools, however, and so your *workspace* would be a geodatabase (for feature classes) or directory (for shapefiles). Working with the spatial data in a geodatabase, workspace is relevant; working with map layouts in a Pro project, workspace is not relevant.

In the first example script, the `arcpy.ListFeatureClasses` tool will not work without the `arcpy.env.workspace` parameter first being set. This is where arcpy can be a little quirky, because other tools (e.g., `arcpy.CreateFeatureClass`) expect the workspace to be passed in as a parameter instead of set as an external parameter.

It takes practice and experience (and/or reading the help pages) to know when the workspace matters and when it doesn't.

Comment: Thank you so much for the informative and well thought through answer!